# Remove cookie policy popup created by ngx-cookieconsent

Tags: cookieconsent

How can I remove the small "Cookie policy" window?
I am using latest version of ngx-cookieconsent with Angular 7.2

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i forced to close it by:
`this.ccService.close(false);`
or to hide by `this.ccService.fadeOut();`

since `'revokable': false` option didnt work.

Comment: Following code `this.ccService.close(false);` does indeed work as suggested by @ya-dimon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late for this answer but had the same issue today and I found some workaround.

```
this.statusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
  (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => {
    if (event.status === 'allow') {
      this.ccService.close(false); // Hide revoke button after accepting cookies
    }        
  });
```

Below this or at the end of `ngOnInit()` I added this:

```
if (this.ccService.hasConsented()) {
  this.ccService.destroy();      
}
```

Code above check if you get consent and if yes it will destroy popup instance.

Comment: Be careful when using `this.ccService.destroy();` because you will destroy the cookieconsent instance and will not be able to interact with it anymore.
example : `this.ccService.hasConsented();` will produce an error.

Comment: but it doesn't permanently disables the pop-up, once I refresh the pop-up reappears... It should be more of cookie dependent thing, so any ways to acheive that?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to add the following in the app.component.scss:

```
/* Hide ng cookies consent revoke button */
::ng-deep  .cc-revoke {
      display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the `this.ccService.getConfig().autoOpen=false` ?
After saving cookie, i set it to false.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.statusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => {
        this.ccService.fadeOut();
      });
    if (this.ccService.hasAnswered()) this.ccService.toggleRevokeButton(false);
}
```